# How to read my ICS file as a meeting email in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, icalendar

I found a method [here](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2008/11/generating-outlook-calendar-invitations-on-the-fly-using-c-and-net/) which creates *.ICS file which I need to send as a email. The problem I am facing is that Outlook 2010 is not reading that as meeting email. Instead, it reads it as a regular email. Here is the code below:

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contype = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
contype.Parameters.Add("name", "Meeting.ics");
AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), contype);
msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: You need more details. How are you generating the ics file? What is the raw output for your file? Are you certain the format is correct?

Comment: Please post the full MIME source of the message that you are sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this working fine:
"Optionally, you could also attach the .ics file itself, so regular mail readers can offer the user something to click on. Outlook does not really require the attachment because it just reads the text/calendar part."